# How to deserialize json date for dygraph native array format

Tags: json, date, datetime, dygraphs, json-deserialization

I was originally passing my unix based integer timestamp to json_encode for use with dygraphs, this actually works except for one problem, you then have to use the xaxis valueFormatter and axisLabelFormatter and the date/time on the axis will not align with the date/time shown in the value legend (top right corner of chart).

here is my original method that works except the legend is wrong, test.php:

```
<?php
    $table[] = [1482407341000,92,86];
    $table[] = [1482407342000,92,86];
    $table[] = [1482407343000,91,85];
    $table[] = [1482407344000,92,85];
    $table[] = [1482407345000,91,84];
    $table[] = [1482407346000,90,83];
    $table[] = [1482407347000,91,82];
    $table[] = [1482407348000,92,82];
    $jsontable = json_encode($table);
    echo $jsontable;
?>
<html><head><script type="text/javascript" src="dygraph-combined-dev.js"></script></head>
<body><div id="graph" style="width:100%; height:96%;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("graph"),
    <?=$jsontable?>,
    {
        legend: 'always',
        labelsDivStyles: { 'textAlign': 'right' },
        labels: ['Date', 'spO2', 'pr'],
        axes: {
        x: {
        valueFormatter: Dygraph.dateString_,
        axisLabelFormatter: Dygraph.dateAxisFormatter,
        ticker: Dygraph.dateTicker
        }
        }
    });
</script></body></html>
```

Now, here is my attempt at a solution, if you actually use a date object then the xaxis will align with the legend (http://jsfiddle.net/b0g9pd1h/), this should work, but dygraphs fails to load, so there must still be a problem with the format of my variable, no error message is displayed so i am unsure why dygraphs does not load.

with dygraphs your value is either going to be an integer/float or it is going to be a string/date, so with my JSON.parse function json_deserialize_helper I am treating all string as a date and attempting to return the date object, the code looks good to me, so I am unsure what I am doing wrong.

test2.php:

```
<?php
    $table[] = ["1482407341000",92,86];
    $table[] = ["1482407342000",92,86];
    $table[] = ["1482407343000",91,85];
    $table[] = ["1482407344000",92,85];
    $table[] = ["1482407345000",91,84];
    $table[] = ["1482407346000",90,83];
    $table[] = ["1482407347000",91,82];
    $table[] = ["1482407348000",92,82];
    $jsontable = json_encode($table);
    echo $jsontable;
?>
<html><head><script type="text/javascript" src="dygraph-combined-dev.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function json_deserialize_helper(key,value) {
    if ( typeof value === 'string' ) {
        return new Date(parseInt(value));
    }
        return value;
    }
</script></head>
<body><div id="graph" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = <?=$jsontable?>;
    var json = JSON.parse(data,json_deserialize_helper);
    g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("graph"),
    json,
    {
        legend: 'always',
        labelsDivStyles: { 'textAlign': 'right' },
        labels: ['Date', 'spO2', 'pr']
    });
</script></body></html>
```

also, maybe this is not the most efficient way of doing this, although parsing the strings to a date object seems pretty efficient to me, if anyone has an alternative solution please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this answer helps you solve a problem your working on, please upvote this post, i'm new to this site.

I got this working, you have to loop through and modify the elements one by one, the below solution works, and the values of both the X axis and and legend are displayed correctly, I can set labelsUTC to true or false, and they both display correctly. The key was using a Date object instead of a date string as I was previously doing.

```
<?php
    $table[] = [1482407341000,92,86];
    $table[] = [1482407342000,92,86];
    $table[] = [1482407343000,91,85];
    $table[] = [1482407344000,92,85];
    $table[] = [1482407345000,91,84];
    $table[] = [1482407346000,90,83];
    $table[] = [1482407347000,91,82];
    $table[] = [1482407348000,92,82];
    $jsontable = json_encode($table);
    //echo $jsontable;
?>
<html><head><script type="text/javascript" src="dygraph-combined-dev.js"></script>
</head><body><div id="graph" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = <?=$jsontable?>;
    //loop through json table and convert unix timestamp to date object:
    for ( var i in data) {
        data[i][0] = new Date(data[i][0]);
    }
    g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("graph"),
    data,
    {
        legend: 'always',
        labelsDivStyles: { 'textAlign': 'right' },
        labels: ['Date', 'spO2', 'pr']
    });
</script></body></html>
```