# How to create a chart in PHP using JSON data from SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, json, dygraphs

I have a sql query which creates a pivot table. Now I've have executed this query in PHP using 'multiquery' and have converted it into JSON using 'json_encode'. The JSON data is consists of around 25million records and the format of each record is

```
{
timestamp: .....;
value 1: .....;
value 2: .....;
value 3: .....;
value 4: .....;
..
..
..
value n: .....;
}
```

Now I need to create a chart from this. How should I convert the JSON data into dynamic array so as to create a chart. I'm using dygraphs library.

Comment: this might help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41540131/how-to-deserialize-json-date-for-dygraph-native-array-format

Comment: Which one are you looking for? Create a chart or convert your array into json?

Comment: 25million records! Good luck loading that.

Answer (score 1):

To convert your json to array you can use json_decode with "true" in second parameters:
json_decode($json, true);

[php doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert JSON string to array by using `json_decode()` function

```
$newArray = json_decode($json_string, TRUE);
```